# gcloud ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [3]

Tags: docker, gcloud

After running `gcloud app deploy` i am having the next error trying to deploy my application to a container using gcloud and the google cloud API.

```
Step 5 : CMD npm start
---> Running in cb3b29e90183
---> 296d95a6ac52
Removing intermediate container cb3b29e90183
Successfully built 296d95a6ac52
PUSH
The push refers to a repository [us.gcr.io/<ID_PROJECT>/appengine/default.20160906t225412] (len: 1)
296d95a6ac52: Preparing
296d95a6ac52: Pushing
296d95a6ac52: Pushed
d6a5f487b829: Preparing
d6a5f487b829: Pushing
d6a5f487b829: Pushed
b71be5d9c21a: Preparing
b71be5d9c21a: Pushing
b71be5d9c21a: Pushed
75d5a58c171b: Preparing
75d5a58c171b: Pushing
75d5a58c171b: Pushed
9ff051f37ab2: Image already exists
363507e00b22: Image already exists
818131a74c7c: Image already exists
cc57a274adf5: Image already exists
c7c7a273971f: Image already exists
b21b3e3bc691: Image already exists
latest: digest:sha256:70668fb04a90187c890eb6ba3119b6af46838a5518f7a96e8996f1d5fda6dc52    size: 33255
DONE
Updating service [default]...failed.

ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [3] Docker image us.gcr.io/<PROJET_ID>/appengine/default.20160906t225412:latest was either not found, or you do not have access to it.
```

I just recently updated my google cloud SDK from the version 122.0.0 to the version 124.0.0 I am running this in my local machine mac environment, this is the complete version's list:

gcloud --version

- Google Cloud SDK 124.0.0
- bq 2.0.24
- bq-nix 2.0.24
- core 2016.08.29
- core-nix 2016.08.29
- gcloud
- gsutil 4.21
- gsutil-nix 4.21

Comment: Is the error reproducible? Does it persist if you downgrade back to 122.0.0 (`gcloud components update --version=122.0.0`)?

Comment: Actually, it always happens on 124.0.0, but we cannot downgrade due to restrictions with the other components in the platform

Comment: Is your project a few years old? You may need to call the [repair](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps/repair) endpoint of the App Engine Admin API; you can do it right from the API Explorer in the browser.

Comment: No really, we are having problems with the new version of the portal (Node v4), the old one (Node 0.12.10) actually works fine, and also tried the API repair https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps/repair and it didn't make the trick neither

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error and the solution, apparently the gcloud SDK version upgrade, from `122.0.0` to `124.0.0` got corrupted my project id in the gcloud portal.

I tried to switch back from `124.0.0` to `122.0.0` unsuccessfully and also upgrade again to `126.0.0`, but finally I found that creating a new project and migrating all my containers made the trick and once there everything worked correctly!.

I have to say it, gcloud is a very useful and powerful tool, but with an error like this and finding out that there is actually few support provide it from Google makes me think to move back to AWS.

Answer (score 0):

App Engine no longer supports Docker V1 format images for new deployments.  It looks like the error message used doesn't really convey this.

Here are the docs on how to tell which docker format an image is in:
https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/ui

We'll work on getting the error message fixed. Sorry about the hassle.

Comment: That is not the problem. My containers are on V2, but I get an identical error, both on v124 and v126 of `gcloud`.

Comment: As Michal said, i actually have 3 containers in V2 and 1 in V1 and only my V2 containers are having this error